# Can't access Webmin from browser after installing

Tags: firewall, services, ufw, webmin, amazon

Fresh Webmin install on  Ubuntu 20.04 on Amazon Lightsail

- I added the line to `iptables` as per their instructions:

  ```
  sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
  ```
- I have added port `10000/tcp` to `ufw` also.
- When I go to the browser https://myip:10000 the browser stays loading for a while then says:

  ```
  cant open the page because the server where this page is located isn't responding
  ```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

When I run `sudo service webmin status` I get this:

```
● webmin.service - LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems  
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/webmin; generated)  
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-02-04 00:52:06 UTC; 55min ago  
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)  

Feb 04 00:52:05 ip-172-26-4-221 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems...  
Feb 04 00:52:05 ip-172-26-4-221 perl[4800]: pam_unix(webmin:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= user=root    
Feb 04 00:52:06 ip-172-26-4-221 webmin[4800]: Webmin starting  
Feb 04 00:52:06 ip-172-26-4-221 systemd[1]: Started LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems.  
lines 1-9/9 (END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OKOK Are you on LightSail?

For me it was the Amazon firewall. I had to allow port 10000 through LightSail console under Network. Even though I had allowed it on ufw through terminal Amazon was applying its own firewall.